# Default redirection behavior does not work in Symfony Security

Tags: security, symfony

This is my security.yml file :

```
security:
encoders:
    Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm: pbkdf2
        iterations: 1000
        encode_as_base64: false

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: AcmeUserBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/login$
        anonymous:  ~
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        access_denied_url: /forbidden
        http_basic: 
            realm: "Zone de sécurité"

        #formulaire de connexion
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/adminBack, roles: ROLE_BACKEND }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I send this url : /web/app_dev.php/adminBack/create/user

it redirects to /login

asks me to sign in

I do

No problem with credentials

BUT it does not redirect to the first url : /web/app_dev.php/adminBack/create/user

Instead it goes to a blank page with only the tool bar : /web/app_dev.php/_wdt/224765

What is wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you check use_referer option ?

Comment: try defining :
`default_target_path: /adminBack/create/user` in form_login

Comment: @BenjaminLazarecki : with use_referer at true it does not change anything.. I still go to this strange page

Comment: @basant : the thing is that there is no default url... everything depends on the url that has been requested

Comment: I thought that the default behaviour of Symfony was to redirect to the requested url (ie Documentation)... but obviously not here.. I must miss something

Comment: PS : I have just tried the default_target_path... it does not change anything, still redirecting to /web/app_dev.php/_wdt/224765

Comment: may be u didn't define route for `/adminBackend/create/user`

Comment: Why do you use 2 firewall ? doc say : "if your firewall does not allow for anonymous users, you'll need to create a special firewall"

Comment: excactly... this is what I am doing there... one special firewall for login so I can go there without authentification and the main one for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add this firewall (or keep it in fact or it will not work)

```
dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
```